# java Most efficient way to generate a nested report?

Tags: java, sorting, reporting

My List contains House objects with the following fields:

```
private Integer address;
private String street;
private double price;
private int rooms;
```

I would like to generate a report that lists the number rooms, how many house have that quantity of rooms, and then a listing of those houses. Similar to below.

## houses with 2 rooms: 3

-Mainstreet, 1112, $45,000.00

-Mainstreet, 1456, $42,200.00

-Oak, 54, 43,600.00

## houses with 3 rooms: 1

-Mainstreet, 1890, $52,000.00

I was thinking of a hashmap with room/quantity key pairs and then using the hashmap to build an array, but there has to be something easier than running a bunch of loops. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
Map<Integer, List<House>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<House>>();
```

Then iterate once over over your list to build the map.

```
for(House h: houses){
    List<House> l = map.get(h.rooms);
    if(l==null){ 
        l = new ArrayList<House>();
        map.put(h.rooms, l);
    }
    l.add(h);
}
```

map.get(3) will return list houses having 3 rooms;

Then you are done.

Comment: So I can use my List as a type for value and my room count as key. Perfect and simple! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which compares the number of rooms then uses the price as a tie breaker. Something like this

```
class HouseComparator implements Comparator<House>{
    public int compare(House a,House b){
        int value = Integer.compare(a.rooms, b.rooms);
        if (value == 0)
        {
             value = Double.compare(a.price, b.price);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Which you can use to sort your list with with the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) class.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you are looking for is a MultiMap. There are several implementations available in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) for java. It handles the inner list from @Pawel Solarski for you.

This would get all of your data organized to run your report on it.

Comment: Sorry, I choose to not use any outside collections for now. @Pawel Solarski 's answer was perfect. Thanks for the suggestion.